# How to join two tables using a comma-separated-list in the join field

Tags: mysql, join, csv

I have two tables, `categories` and `movies`.

In `movies` table I have a column `categories`. That column consists of the categories that movie fits in. The categories are IDs separated by a comma.

Here's an example:

```
Table categories {
  -id-       -name-
  1          Action
  2          Comedy
  4          Drama
  5          Dance
}

Table movies {
  -id-       -categories-  (and some more columns ofc)
  1          2,4
  2          1,4
  4          3,5
}
```

Now to the actual question: Is it possible to perform a query that excludes the categories column from the movies table, and instead selects the matching categories from the categories table and returns them in an array? Like a join, but the problem is there are multiple categories separated by comma, is it possible to do some kind of regex?

Comment: Why aren't you normalizing to three tables; Movies, Categories, MoviesCategories?

Comment: What do you mean by saying return them in an array?

Comment: Can you improve on the question title? A list of technologies does not describe the problem. That's what tags are.

Comment: @Brad, that is a really good idea. I didn't think of that when creating the database. It would have made it a lot easier for me. How about the speed? Would it be a lot more processor heavy if i seperate them into a third table?

Comment: @Johan: I was hoping the OP could gain the experience of doing it herself!

Comment: @Katie: It will be vastly _more_ efficient (in general), because that is how relational databases are _designed to work_.

Comment: @Tomale: Great! I've separated the tables so now i have "movies", "categories" and "movies_categories". I'm having some trouble writing the query though. It almost works as i want it now, the only problem is that i want to get all categories, not just the first one. Is it possible to concatenate the categories by a comma? Here's my query: `SELECT movies.*, categories.name FROM movies LEFT JOIN movies_categories ON (movies.id = movies_categories.movie_id) LEFT JOIN categories ON (movies_categories.category_id = categories.id)`

Comment: And also, for some reason i'm not able to add a WHERE clause which i definately need. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using comma separated lists in a database field is an anti-pattern and should be avoided at all costs.
Because it is a PITA to extract those comma separated values out agian in SQL.

Instead you should add a separate link table to represent the relationship between categories and movies, like so:

```
Table categories
  id integer auto_increment primary key
  name varchar(255)

Table movies
  id integer auto_increment primary key
  name varchar(255)

Table movie_cat
  movie_id integer foreign key references movies.id
  cat_id integer foreign key references categories.id
  primary key (movie_id, cat_id)
```

Now you can do

```
SELECT m.name as movie_title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS categories FROM movies m
INNER JOIN movie_cat mc ON (mc.movie_id = m.id)
INNER JOIN categories c ON (c.id = mc.cat_id)
GROUP BY m.id
```

**Back to your question**
Alternativly using your data you can do

```
SELECT m.name as movie_title
  , CONCAT(c1.name, if(c2.name IS NULL,'',', '), ifnull(c2.name,'')) as categories 
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON 
 (replace(substring(substring_index(m.categories, ',', 2),
  length(substring_index(m.categories, ',', 2 - 1)) + 1), ',', '') = c2.id)
INNER JOIN categories c1 ON 
 (replace(substring(substring_index(m.categories, ',', 1), 
  length(substring_index(m.categories, ',', 1 - 1)) + 1), ',', '') = c1.id)
```

Note that the last query only works if there are 2 or fewer categories per movie.

Comment: @Johan I have this code working great but i would like to do more than 2. What would I have to change?

Comment: What's `movie_cat`.`id` for?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, every table **must** have a primary key. (or suffer all kinds of handicaps).

Comment: @Johan: That doesn't mean you have to create a meaningless and arbitrary auto-incrementing integer field for it. Put the primary key on `(movie_id,cat_id)` for crying out loud! This `movie_cat`.`id` is 100% pointless.

Answer (score 21):

```
select
    m.id,
    group_concat(c.name)
from
    movies m
    join categories c on find_in_set(c.id, m.categories)
group by
    m.id
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Table movies {
  -id-       -categories-
  1          Comedy,Drama
  2          Action,Drama
  4          Other,Dance
}
```

Comment: There is at least one syntax error here. I think if you add the comma after `movies m` and change the `ON` to a `WHERE` (you're not using written-out `JOIN` syntax) then you'll get that output. But I can't see where this `"Other"` has come from?

Comment: @Tomalak It was a typo. I forgot to add `join`. I don't like to write join conditions in WHERE clause. **Other** is just an example, it depends on `categories` table.

Answer (score 4):

Brad is right; normalisation is the solution. *Normalisation exists to solve this problem.* It should be covered pretty well in your MySQL book if it's worth its salt.

---

If you really insist, though, you can fake the direct join by cross-matching with `FIND_IN_SET` (which conveniently expects a comma-delimited string of items).

Now, MySQL can't return "an array" — that's what sets of results are for — but it can give you the category names separated by, say, a pipe (`|`):

```
SELECT
       `m`.`id`,
       `m`.`name`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(`c`.`name` SEPARATOR "|") AS `cats`
  FROM
       `movies`     AS `m`,
       `categories` AS `c`
 WHERE
       FIND_IN_SET(`c`.`id`, `m`.`categories`) != 0
 GROUP BY
       `m`.`id`;
```

Result:

```
id  "name"     "cats"
---------------------------------------------------
1   "Movie 1"  "Comedy|Drama"
2   "Movie 2"  "Action|Drama"
4   "Movie 4"  "Dance"
```

Comment: How we can join more than one table in this scenario ?

Comment: @GaneshAher: That's going to be tough, which is another reason that this is the wrong tool for the job! Use a join.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT m.*, c.* FROM movies m 
RIGHT JOIN categories c on find_in_set(c.id, m.categories) 
GROUP BY m.id
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't directly answering your question but what you have in the `movies` table is really bad.

Instead of combining `categories` using comma, what you should be doing is to have each category on separate rows, eg:

```
Table movies {
  -id-       -categories-
  1          2
  1          4
  2          1
  2          4
  4          3
  4          5
}
```

Comment: No, this is bad too. The movie-category relation should be in a separate table; you've just duplicated all of the "other columns" in `movies`.