# How to represent Cross Apply and Split String in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, t-sql, split

For some background, what i'm trying to do create a database that contains multiple recipes. However, it's necessary for the individual ingredients to be linked to the recipe they originally came from.

For instance, I have table containing all the individual ingredients.

[image]

And a table where the recipes are stored, minus the ingredients.

[image]

Now, i've found [this](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles//t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) article which covers how to split strings using T-SQL XML Commands, and the code that is used to do so is:

```
SELECT
  Books.BookId,
  Books.Book,
  BookAuthors.AuthorId,
  BookAuthors.Author
FROM Books
CROSS APPLY dbo.split(Books.Authors,',') split
INNER JOIN BookAuthors ON BookAuthors.AuthorId = split.val
```

The result i'm looking for would be very similar to this:
[image]

However, CROSS APPLY etc only works on MS SQL Server and my question is:

**Is it possible to achieve the same, or very similar effect using MySQL?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Strongly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861258/how-to-join-two-tables-using-a-comma-separated-list-in-the-join-field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should quite match what you're trying to get:

```
SELECT
  Books.BookId,
  Books.Book,
  BookAuthors.AuthorId,
  BookAuthors.Author
FROM Books
  LEFT JOIN BookAuthors ON (find_in_set(BookAuthors.AuthorId, Books.Authors) <> 0)
```

Found this article very helpful: [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Leave a comment if you need further explanation how it works.