# Select data from tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to SQL tables:

Table 1 (`Recipes`):

```
Name        Ingredients
----------------------------------
ciorba      apa,sare,piper,branza  
paste       branza,oua,lapte
```

Table 2 (`Ingredients` liked by user):

```
Name       Ingredients
-------------------------
ionutG     branza  
vasile     oua,lapte
```

I want to select recipes from table 1 that contains one ore more liked ingredients from table 2.

Ex : For ionutG I want to retrieve both recipes because there are liked ingredients. And for vasile I want to retrieve only the second recipe.

Note that the tables are larger and there are so many entries.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    a.Nume 
FROM
    reteta a 
JOIN 
    ingredientplacut b ON (a.Ingrediente = b.Ingrediente);
```

But it returns me only the recipes that have exact the same ingredients which I don't want. I want to return the recipes that have one or multiple liked ingredients not all.

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that you are storing lists of items as a string.  This is a bad idea.  Fix your data structure to use junction tables, and the SQL will be (relatively) easy.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution for my problem because one user can have so many liked ingredients that means one row in the table for each liked ingredient.Anyways maybe I 'm wrong and you can give me a solution if you are well willing.You can use the tables described above.

Comment: Gordon is right. You should read up on "normalization". You have a many-to-many relationship which should be modeled with a link table between recipes and ingredients. Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using HeidiSQL

Comment: "... that means one row in the table for each liked ingredient". If you do it right, your tables will contain only two numbers each row: (recipe_id, ingredient_id) and (user_id, ingredient_id)

Comment: HeidiSQL is not a DBMS, it's a SQL client that can connect to different database systems

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand right. I am using MySQL

Comment: I am not able to store ingredients of a recipe in multiple rows,all ingredients will be stored into a single row.Also I can store liked ingredients into one or multiple rows.So I have to find a solution to compare those strings and if are matched partial or not I need to select that recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try exists
Like for example

```
 Select a.name from table 1 where exists (select b.name from table 2 where a.ingredient = b.name);
```

Please note that this might not be correct syntax. So it returns all recipes where exists will return true. So where one or more ingredients are same.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on storing data like you do, a possible solution (tested in T-SQL, question does not specify SQL flavor):

**Setup**

```
create table Recipes 
(
    RecipeId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_Recipes PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Ingredients NVARCHAR(4000)
)
GO

insert into Recipes (Name, Ingredients) VALUES ('ciorba', 'apa,sare,piper,branza'), ('paste', 'branza,oua,lapte')
GO


create table Ingredients
(
    IngredientId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_Ingredients PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Ingredients NVARCHAR(4000)
)
GO

insert into Ingredients (Name, Ingredients) VALUES ('ionutG', 'branza'), ('vasile', 'oua,lapte')
GO
```

-- cannot remember what is the source for this - probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );

GO

select * from Recipes
select * from Ingredients
GO

-- split strings and retrieve records where intersection is not null
select distinct I.Name, I.Ingredients, R.Name 
FROM Ingredients I
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(Ingredients, ',') IToken
JOIN Recipes R
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(Ingredients, ',') RToken
        ON RToken.Item = IToken.Item
```

**Note:**. As already mentioned, you should really consider normalizing your data:

**1) Performance** - string operations are expensive and they should be avoided

**2) Hard to write queries** - a basic query for finding out common items uses a user defined function

**3) Bad for application development** - consider that the client also requires an English version for the application. Currently, all items are in Romanian. How to you handle this situation?

**4) Bad for reports** - consider that your structure requires extensive querying for reports regarding ingredients usage and other information. Those reports will have complex and messy queries which will be slow

[EDIT] For MySQL the following references may be used to replace unsupported features shown above:

Split strings using a method shown [here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql.html).
Related questions and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591779/how-to-represent-cross-apply-and-split-string-in-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861258/how-to-join-two-tables-using-a-comma-separated-list-in-the-join-field).

Comment: I am not able to store ingredients of a recipe in multiple rows,all ingredients will be stored into a single row.Also I can store liked ingredients into one or multiple rows.So I have to find a solution to compare those strings and if are matched partial or not I need to select that recipe.

Comment: Why not? You can have a table of `Ingredients` and define X tables: `RecipeXIngredient` and `UserXIngredient`. X tables will use just ids (integers) and the queries are simpler. Also, space used by tables is significantly smaller.